# Hive Metastore for S3 Objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive-metastore

My requirement is to setup Hive Metastore for the files that ingested into Data lake (Amazon S3) through some ETL tool. Would like to know how to setup Hive Metastore for the S3 files ?

Could you please share some thought on know how to setup it ?